# Такой мальчик(,) и не нашел себе возлюбленную

Tags: запятые

Обоснуйте, пожалуйста, наличие или отсутствие запятой в предложении "Такой мальчик(,) и не нашел себе возлюбленную".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Такой мальчик, и не нашел себе возлюбленную.***

1. Заглянем сначала в словарь:

**ТАКОЙ**  2. Выражает сильную степень свойства, состояния или **усиления оценки**. Т. красивый.  Он т. силач! Т-ая тоска на сердце! Не стоит думать о таких пустяках. Т-ая досада! Раздался т. гром, что все испугались.

**Союз И** 4. Соединяет предложения и члены предложения, представляющие собой **противопоставляемые** высказывания. Он хотел испугать её и испугался сам. Всё было уже готово, и всё-таки медлили начинать.  Хотел объехать целый свет, И не объехал сотой доли (Грибоедов).

В этом случае возможна замена  союзами ***А, НО***.

2. Теперь перефразируем предложение: ***Такой  (интересный, красивый, умный, богатый) мальчик,  а не нашел себе возлюбленную.***

Признак **не называется**, он определяется по контексту, **по ситуации**.

Например: – *Как не стыдно, Фандорин, – сказала она жалостно и посмотрела на Ластика, словно на покойника. – **Такая (прекрасная) семья, такой  (знаменитый) прадедушка!***

**Вывод:** запятая ставится **перед союзом И**, который имеет в данном случае значение **противительного** союза.

Answer (score 1):

Мне думается, что ответ здесь прост. Налицо присоединительный оборот, в котором союз "и" употребляется в значении "и притом", а такие обороты, как известно, отделяются запятой.